# how to use rdfcat from java code

Tags: java, jena

in jena api there is the class rdfcat ,it is a tool to convert data file format 
,it could be used from commande line just like the example ,
i need to execute the tool from inside java code ,
i tried the code but i failed .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    rdfcat rdf=new rdfcat();

    String[] t={"-x f:/foaf.owl -out ttl"};
    rdf.main(t);

    String string=rdf.getCheckedLanguage("owl");
    System.out.println("************************************************************");
    Map<String,String> m=rdf.unabbreviate;
    Iterator iterator =m.keySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())System.out.println(iterator.next());
    System.out.println("************************************************************");
    System.out.println(string);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing Jena specific about this.  The command line arguments are supposed to be an *array* of the various arguments, but you're passing just one.  That is,

```
String[] t={"-x f:/foaf.owl -out ttl"};
```

is an array with *one* String as a member.  If you're going to call rdfcat's main, you'd need to do:

```
String[] t={"-x", "f:/foaf.owl", "-out", "ttl"};
```

That said, this seems like a kind of strange thing to do.  You could almost as easily, but much more flexibly, load the input into a model and then write it out in any format that you want.

Comment: thanks , johuna taylor, yes that's exactly what i need to do , there is a web service from Manchester university  here mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/ , it work with owlapi , i need to implement it in java code , if u have another way to convert file format  by jena it would be better

Comment: yes i find it ,OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC);
        model.read("file:///f:/foaf.owl");
  
  FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream(new File("f:/file.owl"));
        model.write(fo,"N-TRIPLE");

Comment: @user3310460 Do you *intend* to write out a model that includes inferences?  The Pellet Reasoner spec will include reasoning.  If you're just trying to convert formats, you can do `Model model = ModelFactory.createDfaultModel();`  It would be good to use a try-with-resources for reading your model, by the way, and RDFDataMgr provides an alternative to Model#write, that will give you some enumeration types for the languages (which can help avoid typos, string comparisons, etc.).